# Spf13 VIM: Not to eat up tabs on empty lines on save

Tags: vim, spf13vim

The wanted behavior for many on Spf13 VIM is to eat up any whitespace or tabs on an empty line. I am working on an existing project, and I've got a lot of these changes in the change log:

[image]

How can I stop Spf13 VIM from deleting these tabs on empty lines?

**Edit:**

Never mind, it does work. Answering my own question now.

Comment: Wouldn't it be preferable to set your diff tool to ignore whitespace?

Comment: Also, I do not believe Vim does this by default; what plugins are you using?

Comment: @KyleStrand: That's Github. I should have mentioned that. I'm using standard Spf13 install.

Comment: @dan-klasson the "standard Spf13" is not standard at all. You don't know what is going on when you are using so called vim-distribution. But if you chose that way, post issue to the author once you got problem.

Comment: @Kent: I mean standard as in the standard install. Haven't added any additional plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this in the Spf13 `.vimrc` file:

```
" To disable the stripping of whitespace, add the following to your
" .vimrc.before.local file:
"   let g:spf13_keep_trailing_whitespace = 1
```

After adding that it worked, also for tabs.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Python-mode](https://github.com/klen/python-mode), maybe setting its `pymode_trim_whitespaces` to zero will help:

```
let g:pymode_trim_whitespaces = 0
```

Comment: I checked and Spf13 seems to be using `python-mode`. But it's not working, I apply the above from within vim. Add a tab on an empty line, save it and exit. And when I open the file again the tab is gone.